# Django "remove hardcoded urls in templates" not working

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm checking out django for the first time following the tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/

So far it's been plain sailing.  I've hit a snag at the Remove hard coded urls section.  I'm using Django 1.6.6.

When I change the hardcoded url from:

```
<li><a href="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
```

to:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
```

I get a 404 error as follows:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/polls/%7B%%20url%20'detail'%20poll.id%20%7D

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^polls/ ^$ [name='index']
^polls/ ^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$ [name='detail']
^polls/ ^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$ [name='results']
^polls/ ^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$ [name='vote']
^admin/

The current URL, polls/{% url 'detail' poll.id }, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file.  Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

The url that shows up in the address bar is

```
mylocalenv/polls/%7B%%20url%20%27detail%27%20poll.id%20%7D
```

I've tried removing the quotes from 'detail' but given I'm on django 1.6.6 I shouldn't need to.  It didn't work either.  I've also tried skipping ahead a bit and including the /polls/ namespace in urls.py but again, no joy.

My urls.py file looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'), 

)
```

The exact code in my index.html template is:

```
{% if latest_poll_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

**Got it**

But frustratingly I have no idea why.  Out of desperation in my index.html I started playing around with the index.html file on this line:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
```

For no logical reason I changed poll.id to poll_id.  Reloading broke index.html as I expected.  When I changed it back to poll.id everything works.  This makes no sense.  I even ctrl^z back to the index.html that previously wasn't working and now that's working too.  I restarted the server before each check.  I'm annoyed.  But at least it's working.

Comment: Looks like this is not the exact code in your template. Can you copy paste the exact code?

Comment: Does the rest of your template actually work? It seems that it's not actually being parsed, so you're getting the raw template tag in your link.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too, but it works fine until I switch the link to the {% url %} tag.  Am I missing an import or something?

Comment: I just came across a similar issue, but later in the tutorial. The index page suddenly stopped working just as you described where it had been fine before and I had not touched it. Rebooting the server fixed it. Must be some glitch in the server.

Answer (score 4):

This line in the trace back suggests you have missed out the `%` before the closing curly brace.

```
The current URL, polls/{% url 'detail' poll.id }, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Yes that's the suggestion.  The trouble is, I haven't!  :)  I've also tried deleting the file and remaking it just to see if something weird is going on.  And renaming it and changing my polls.urls from index to index1.  Still get the same error and the missing %

Comment: I think it was more likely that the poll.id was set to ```"{% url 'detail' poll.id }"``` since it was recognizing the url template tag as valid. Since that's a string and the poll_id needs to be a number, it failed. If it was because you were missing the % before the closing curly brace, then it would have raised a syntax error in the template.

Comment: @schillingt if `poll.id` was not a number, then I think you'd get `NoReverseMatch`. Anyway, it doesn't really matter, the question is a year old, so the OP hopefully solved their problem already.

Answer (score 1):

Even, I was facing this problem and for me the reason was that I gave space between `{ %` and  `% }`, where as the correct syntax is `{%` and `%}`. For completeness I have given the correct and incorrect syntax below -

correct syntax - `<li><a href="{% url 'detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>`

incorrect syntax - `<li><a href="{ % url 'detail' poll.id % }">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>`

Answer (score 1):

check you polls/urls.py file, make sure your urlpatterns is [], not {}

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted the server and interestingly it just worked.